# When the return within useEffect got execute?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have the following pseudo code

```
const handleUploadValidateResult = useCallback(e => {
    if (everything good) {
      do something
    } else {
      do something else
    }
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
    const eventName = `${context}_${type}_${index}`;
    window.addEventListener(eventName, e => {
      handleUploadValidateResult(e);
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener(eventName, e => {
        handleUploadValidateResult(e);
      });
    };

  }, [type, index]);
```

What is the execution order for the return statement

```
return () => {
...
}
```

When `type or index` got changed, is return statement executed

1. before useEffect?
2. or after useEffect?

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` it called after `type` or `index` changes. `return` function is called before the component is unmounted.

Comment: can I confirm that end to end sequence: 1. When 1st time type / index change, useEffect code will run, then return a clean-up func. 2. When 2nd time type / index changed, useEffect code will run, then return another clean-up func??? 3. Now finally the component is unmounted, actually two clean-up func will run???